# mysql indexes changing

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, indexing

I'm going to write searching script in php (in mysql databases), so I'm going to do it with indexes (to speed up). I've html form like this

HTML :

```
<select name="search">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="surname">Surname</option>
    <option value="etc">Etc.</option>
</select>
```

So I'm going to write mysql indexes like so => , for example if selected name, i want to create index in database with name column and after result want to delete that index (this everything with php), and I going to do so for every select options, So I am interested in is that way right, and if it isn't how can I do that ? Also that table will not be updated, but also it can add some other data and in this situation will I have problems with indexes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your method is to create a new index on a column each time that column is searched?

**This is absolutely not correct.** Creating an index can be a very slow process if you have any real amount of data in the table. Create the index/indices one time. Then they'll always be there when a column field is searched against. Especially if the *"table will not be updated"* as you say. I have never encountered a situation where programmatically creating then deleting an index is the right way to go.

It's worth noting that when you create a new index MySQL builds a separate block of information that must then be updated every time changes are made in the table. If you have a very large amount of data in the table AND make frequent changes (forcing the index to be constantly updated) you could experience some performance issues. I get the feeling this is not your situation, however.

Comment: so can I have for example created some indexes (for instance 4) ? and also in some index have for example 2 column ?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. MySQL is pretty good at determining the best available index to use for a query. I suggest you read [The Fine MySQL Manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) on how MySQL uses indexes.